# How to decode json into structs

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to decode some json in Go but some fields don't get decoded. 
See the code running  in browser [here](http://play.golang.org/p/ZunE4_lKKv):

What am I doing wrong?

I need only the MX records so I didn't define the other fields. As I understand from the godoc you don't need to define the fields you don't use/need.

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

func main() {

    body := `
  {"response": {
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "data": {
    "mxRecords": [
      {
        "value": "us2.mx3.mailhostbox.com.",
        "ttl": 1,
        "priority": 100,
        "hostName": "@"
      },
      {
        "value": "us2.mx1.mailhostbox.com.",
        "ttl": 1,
        "priority": 100,
        "hostName": "@"
      },
      {
        "value": "us2.mx2.mailhostbox.com.",
        "ttl": 1,
        "priority": 100,
        "hostName": "@"
      }
    ],
    "cnameRecords": [
      {
        "aliasHost": "pop.a.co.uk.",
        "canonicalHost": "us2.pop.mailhostbox.com."
      },
      {
        "aliasHost": "webmail.a.co.uk.",
        "canonicalHost": "us2.webmail.mailhostbox.com."
      },
      {
        "aliasHost": "smtp.a.co.uk.",
        "canonicalHost": "us2.smtp.mailhostbox.com."
      },
      {
        "aliasHost": "imap.a.co.uk.",
        "canonicalHost": "us2.imap.mailhostbox.com."
      }
    ],
    "dkimTxtRecord": {
      "domainname": "20a19._domainkey.a.co.uk",
      "value": "\"v=DKIM1; g=*; k=rsa; p=DkfbhO8Oyy0E1WyUWwIDAQAB\"",
      "ttl": 1
    },
    "spfTxtRecord": {
      "domainname": "a.co.uk",
      "value": "\"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.mailhostbox.com\"",
      "ttl": 1
    },
    "loginUrl": "us2.cp.mailhostbox.com"
  }
}}`

    type MxRecords struct {
        value    string
        ttl      int
        priority int
        hostName string
    }



    type Data struct {
        mxRecords []MxRecords
    }

    type Response struct {
        Status string `json:"status"`
        Data   Data   `json:"data"`
    }
    type apiR struct {
        Response Response
    }

    var r apiR
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err was %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("decoded is %v", r)

}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As per the go documentaiton about [json.Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshal), you can only decode toward **exported fields**, the main reason being that external packages (such as `encoding/json`) cannot acces unexported fields.

If your json doesn't follow the go convention for names, you can use the `json` tag in your fields to change the matching between json key and struct field.

Exemple:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type T struct {
    Foo  string `json:"foo"`
    priv string `json:"priv"`
}

func main() {
    text := []byte(`{"foo":"bar", "priv":"nothing"}`)
    var t T
    err := json.Unmarshal(text, &t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t.Foo) // prints "bar"
    fmt.Println(t.priv) // prints "", priv is not exported
}
```

Comment: What is the significance of `json:"foo"` in struct?

Comment: @DevendraBhat the tag says what will be the name of serialized field in json. Without the tag it would serialize to capitalized `{"Foo": "bar"}`

Comment: added an example with unexported field

Answer (score 12):

You must Uppercase struct fields:

```
type MxRecords struct {
    Value    string `json:"value"`
    Ttl      int    `json:"ttl"`
    Priority int    `json:"priority"`
    HostName string `json:"hostName"`
}

type Data struct {
    MxRecords []MxRecords `json:"mxRecords"`
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/EEyiISdoaE

Answer (score 1):

The `encoding/json` package can only decode into exported struct fields.  Your `Data.mxRecords` member is not exported, so it is ignored when decoding.  If you rename it to use a capital letter, the JSON package will notice it.

You will need to do the same thing for all the members of your `MxRecords` type.